# Find a Hamiltonian circuit in a given Hamiltonian graph.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, hamiltonian-path

I am wonder if there is a polynomial time algorithm(may be probabilistic) that can compute a Hamiltonian circuit in a graph which is known as Hamiltonian graph without other assumption. If there is,plz notify me. Thx!